# find the derivative of $F(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{t^2}dt$ and explain how you got it.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

find the derivative of $F(x)=\int_0^{x^2}e^{t^2}dt$ and explain how you got it.

I tried integration but I think that is not what I am supposed to be doing. But I am still lost here. I would appreciate your help, hints or leads about what I might have missed or overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $G(x) =\int_0^x e^{t^2} dt$, then $F(x) = G(x^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

First define
$$
h(x)=\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,dt,
$$
then $h'(x)=e^{x^2}$. Since $F(x)=h(x^2)$, using the chain rule we get:
$$
F'(x)=2xh'(x^2)=2xe^{x^4}.
$$

Comment: How can one be sure $h'(x)=e^{x^2}$?

Comment: It is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I know that theorem, but I don't know how can you tell that this is the derivative. I don't know how it fulfills the theorem.

Comment: What about 0? I really wan't to know. It is so frustrating I have been wasting 45 minutes trying to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we start off with what an indefinite integral *means*. It means that we take the function and evaluate the anti-derivative at two endpoints, subtracting one from the other. If I differentiate something I integrated and evaluated, what do I get?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Leibniz integral rule for this. Link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule